# Increase frame size of FBLoginView

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Is this possible to increase the frame size of `FBLoginView`?

if yes then how I could do that using facebook iOS SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initialize it you can set the frame size:

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 300.0, 100.0)];
```

Another way is if you do the normal init, you can set the frame size afterwards:

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 300.0, 100.0);
loginview.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: Are u sure it should work because i already tried it and its not working. Can u send me working example of this. Anyways thanks for ur response.

Comment: do you have [loginview sizeToFit]; after ?